# node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, grpc, yarnpkg

I executed `yarn install` on Ubuntu terminal in voicy-master Directory (installing voicy-bot)  .

System Versions:

- node version is 10.8.0
- npm version is 6.3
- operating system Ubuntu 16.04

I got this log after running the command (the error is about grpc package  ) :

```
 root@jalal-INVALID:/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master# yarn install
```

> due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(),
>   Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
>       [4/5] Linking dependencies...
>       [5/5] Building fresh packages...
>       [1/2] ⠈ grpc
>       error /home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
>       Exit code: 1
>       Command: ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>       Arguments: 
>       Directory: /home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc
>       Output:
>       node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
>       node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
>       node-pre-gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
>       node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
>       node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   (not found)
>       node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.0/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc.tar.gz
>       node-pre-gyp http 403 https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.0/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc.tar.gz
>       node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.0/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc.tar.gz
>
> ```
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.13.0 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with
> ```
>
> node-gyp) 
>       node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.0/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc.tar.gz
>
> ```
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.13.0 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to
> ```
>
> source compile with node-gyp) 
>       node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
>       gypgyp info it worked if it ends with ok
>        info it worked if it ends with ok
>       gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
>       gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
>       gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
>       gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
>       gypgyp  infoinfo  okok
>
> ```
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
> gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
> gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
> gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
> gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
> gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
> gyp info gypspawn args   '-f',
> gyp info spawn args   'make',
>  gyp infoinfo  spawn args   '-I',
> spawngyp  /usr/bin/python2
> info spawn args   '/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> gypgyp info  spawn argsinfo   '/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
> gyp  infospawn args spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
>    '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
> gypgyp  info infospawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
>  gypspawn args info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0',
> gyp   'binding.gyp',
>  infogyp  spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
> gypinfo info  spawn argsspawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
>    '-f',
> gyp gypinfo spawn args    '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc',
> infogyp  info spawn argsspawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
>    'make',
> gyp gypinfo  spawn argsinfo   '--depth=.',
> gyp  spawn argsinfo    '-I',
> spawn args   '--no-parallel',
> gypgyp  infoinfo spawn args    '--generator-output',
> spawn argsgyp    '/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
> info gypspawn args   'build',
>  gyp infoinfo  spawn argsspawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
>    '-I',
> gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.node-gyp/10.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
> gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
> gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
> gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
> gyp info spawn args   'build',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
> gyp info ok 
> gyp info ok 
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
> gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
> gyp info using node@10.8.0 | linux | ia32
> gyp info spawn make
> gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
> gyp info spawn make
> gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
> make: Entering directory '/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/build'
> make: Entering directory '/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/build'
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
>
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_record_protocol_crypter_common.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_seal_privacy_integrity_crypter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_unseal_privacy_integrity_crypter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/frame_handler.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_client.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_tsi_event.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_tsi_handshaker.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_integrity_only_record_protocol.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_privacy_integrity_record_protocol.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_record_protocol_common.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_iovec_record_protocol.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_zero_copy_grpc_protector.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_linux.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_no_op.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_client_options.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_options.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_server_options.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_service_api.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_service_api_util.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_tsi_utils.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/transport_security_common_api.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/altscontext.pb.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/handshaker.pb.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/transport_security_common.pb.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_common.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_decode.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_encode.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/authority.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/chttp2_connector.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/backup_poller.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_factory.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_plugin.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/connector.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_connect_handshaker.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_proxy.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy_factory.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy_registry.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/method_params.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/parse_address.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper_registry.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_registry.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/retry_throttle.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel_index.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/uri_parser.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts_transport_security.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/fake_transport_security.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_boringssl.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_cache.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_openssl.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security_grpc.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure/secure_channel_create.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_plugin.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_transport.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/client_load_reporting_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_channel_secure.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_client_stats.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/proto/grpc/lb/v1/load_balancer.pb.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/fake/fake_resolver.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_robin/round_robin.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper_fallback.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/sockaddr/sockaddr_resolver.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/load_reporting/server_load_reporting_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/load_reporting/server_load_reporting_plugin.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/census/grpc_context.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/max_age/max_age_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/message_size/message_size_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/client_authority_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_cronet_compression_filter.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_utils.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/plugin_registry/grpc_plugin_registry.o
>   AR(target) Release/obj.target/libgrpc.a
>   COPY Release/libgrpc.a
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/arena.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/atm.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_iphone.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_linux.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_linux.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/host_port.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_android.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/mpscq.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/murmur_hash.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_util_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_precise.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tls_pthread.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_msys.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/wrap_memcpy.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/fork.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/thd_posix.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/thd_windows.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/profiling/basic_timers.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/profiling/stap_timers.o
>   AR(target) Release/obj.target/libgpr.a
>   COPY Release/libgpr.a
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/call.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/call_credentials.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/channel.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/channel_credentials.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/completion_queue.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/node_grpc.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/server.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/server_credentials.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/slice.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/timeval.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node.node
>   COPY Release/grpc_node.node
>   COPY /home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-ia32-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
> make: Leaving directory '/home/jalal/Desktop/voicy-master/node_modules/grpc/build'
> gyp info ok
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this
> ```

Comment: Sometimes it's beacause of internet failure!

Answer (score 6):

maybe downgrade node to stable version solves the problem:

```
[sudo] npm cache clean -f
[sudo] npm install -g n stable
```

and in project directory `yarn install` again.

Comment: I have downgraded to LTS and that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13673 Might be similar.

BTW, please format console output of the question.